# Font not available in MapInfo v11

Tags: mapinfo

I have a font called Univers 55 on my PC (Windows XP). I would like to 
use this in MapInfo but it is unavailable in the font drop down.

Does anyone know how it would be possible to make this font available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is this font (and you go it from here): http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?productid=47762

I would think the problem is that the format isn't supported by MapInfo Pro. MapInfo Pro doesn't support the OpenType fonts.

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem with OpenType fonts. It is described officially here with some workaround: https://support.pitneybowes.com/VFP06_KnowledgeWithSidebarTroubleshoot?id=kA280000000CpqKCAS&popup=false&lang=en_US

> **Issue** 
>   User installs a font with a .otf extensions and the font works
>   in Word, etc. but is not available in Professional.
>
> **Cause** 
>   MapInfo Pro does not formerly support Open Type Fonts any more
>   since there were changes made to MapInfo Pro 9.0 to only display True
>   Type fonts (.ttf) in the font picker dialog. This was done mainly for
>   Curved Label support, where non-true type fonts can't be used.
>
> **Resolution** UPDATED: October 25, 2017 Here is a workaround that is not
>   officially supported but it may work:
>
> As the non-True Type font is explicitly referenced in places such as
>   Workspaces it should appear in the picker. What this means is that
>   once a font is being used by MapInfo Pro (EG: it has been referenced
>   in a Workspace and then loaded) it will then be included with the font
>   picker dialog.
>
> In order to achieve this please:
>
> 1. Open a table
> 2. Add some text to the cosmetic layer
> 3. Edit the workspace to change the font to your font name.otf font
> 4. In MapInfo Pro, close all, and reopened the workspace. This font will then appear in the font list dropdown. You can again do a close
>      all, and that font should remain in the dropdown for the remainder of
>      the MapInfo Pro session
>
> Since we only support True Type fonts our recommendations would be to
>   use only True Type fonts and there are converters available on the
>   internet that will convert fonts for you, but if you wish to try this
>   workaround you should be able to get a non-True Type font to display
>   in MapInfo Pro.
>
> Note: there are .otf to .ttf conversion programs to be found on the
>   web that may work but note that Converting proprietary fonts to other
>   formats is illegal; you should convert only fonts that have
>   non-restrictive licenses or that you have a license to use.

Comment: Can you give a summary of the link content because the site may get offline someday.

Comment: @MrXsquared do I need to reproduce all the text from the article referenced in the answer? I thought I already gave a short summary.